# How do I dynamically set the path of a file Python?

Tags: python, path, python-os

I am collaborating with a friend. We are working on the same script. The script loads a file. We both access the file in different locations(not the working directory).

I don't want any friction when downloading his script and running it on my local computer. One way I thought about was setting the path as one of the parametres of the script. What approach would you recommend I am using a conda environment, maybe one can set some environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you use file for example in a function just pass file path as a parameter. Thats the simplest solution, but it works well.

Comment: But I would have to change the file everytime he makes an update with this approach?